# Incandescent light bulb in proteus

Tags: light, proteus, model

How to create a simulation model of The incandescent light bulb in Proteus?

Comment: Simulations are _always_ simplifications of reality: one cannot account for everything.  So -- what properties of an incandescent light bulb do you wish to simulate?  Please _edit your question_ to either describe the circuit you're designing, or the properties of an incandescent bulb that are important to you, or both.

Comment: The parameters are 12V 40W 400lm it should be  part of regulation circuit I need to simulate transmission characteristics between luminosity and voltage

Comment: Please **edit your question** so that it is complete.  Stackexchange wants complete questions that can be properly answered, so that readers don't need to dredge through comments to find the "actual" question.  If Proteus doesn't already model luminosity vs. voltage, you need to do that -- do you know that relationship?  Can you **edit your question** with the math that describes it?

Comment: @noName To create a simulation model, you start by thoroughly informing yourself not only of the relevant subjects at hand but also many of the possibly irrelevant ones that surround the topic and may matter, as you become more aware of them. You study the matter and related topics. Then narrow down the list to what you decide to care about. Then you carefully define what it is you expect to achieve with the simulation, now that you've mastered the topic at hand and its related topics. Then you proceed with the process of figuring out how to implement it in Proteus, with tools they provide.